# How do I make other classes change their color when dark mode is on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I implemented a darkmode to my website but it only changes the color of the body and the stuff in the body. It doesn't work for other elements. For example, the navigation bar background and text stays the same color when I would like it to change. Basically I want to make it so that the dark mode style changes everything on the page. I think the reason it's not changing is because the navigation bar has it's own style class so when I add the class with javascript it doesn't override it. I'm not sure if this is why. This is what I have. I tried to see if toggling the class would work but still the same.

```
   <div class= 'nav-bar'>
    <div class="logo"><a href="#home">SS</a> </div>
    <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
         <li><a href='home.html'>Home</a></li> 
         <li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li>
         <li><a href='random.html'>Random</a></li>
         <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="darkmode">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>
     </ul>


.dark {
 background-color: rgba(4, 25, 55    , 1);
 color: white;
 }



let checkbox = document.getElementById("darkmode");
let body = document.getElementById('body')
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode')

function setTheme() {
body.classList.add('dark')
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode','on')}

function removeTheme(){
body.classList.remove('dark')
localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null)
}

if(darkMode === 'on') {
setTheme()
checkbox.checked = true;

}

checkbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode')
if (darkMode !== 'on') {
    setTheme()
} else {
    removeTheme()
} 
})
```

Comment: when you set a class on an element, it's only on that element (body, in your code) ; if other elements have some css rule to set a specific background-color, you will have to also deal with them, by applying a darkmode rule on them

Comment: U can learn css variable and use the concept for themeing. I will recommend to using css not javascript. It will be very hard to modify and work with javascript

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-better-themes-with-css-variables-5a3744105c74/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
.customBackground {
  background: black;
}
.dark .customBackground {
  background: white;
}
```

So that the customBackground class renders differently depending on if there is a .dark ancestor.

The other way you can do it if you are toggling `dark` on and off is

```
H1.dark.customBackground {
  background:white;
}
```